# Memory issue when Selecting 14582 row in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

I have a `raw` measurement with:

```
fields: 
delta: float
fetch_characteristic: string

tags: 
conso_prod
fetch_method
meter_id
operation_id
source
timestep
to_compute
unit
```

After inserting in InfluxDB, I want to make a query:

```
SELECT * FROM raw WHERE to_compute=true
```

This query will run all days, the initial query should select 14582 raws, and then it will select just the last day's raws, so just a few.

I tried to optimize [serie cardinality](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/spec/#show-cardinality), but it didn't give me any improvements.

To run this query, I need 4 GB in RAM, how can I optimize it ?

Comment: Did you try other TSDBs such as TimescaleDB or VictoriaMetrics? They can perform such a query much faster. See [this article](https://medium.com/@valyala/measuring-vertical-scalability-for-time-series-databases-in-google-cloud-92550d78d8ae) for example, which contains [TSBS benchmark](https://github.com/timescale/tsbs/) results for InfluxDB, TimescaleDB and VictoriaMetrics.